# Is there a pythonic way to convert int to string and then concatenate to form a single string value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.float32 array with 9 columns named predict. The array us filled with 0's and 1's (float). I would like to convert the numbers into string then concatenate to form a single value.

e.g.
Before

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

I would like this to become

00000100 (as a string)

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to write, e.g., some `for` loop to do this?

Comment: Have you tried *anything at all*? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have tried to convert the numbers to strings and then concatenate but I am unable to.

Comment: I tried this too but no luck 'np.apply_along_axis(np.array_str,0,predict_5)[0]'

Comment: Maybe with numpy we can do it a bit more efficient, but simple way is `''.join(map(lambda x: f'{x:.0f}', array))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting between numpy and primitive python types is a bit messy, and should be avoided if possible. Nonetheless, there are ways of doing it. [`np.array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html#numpy-array2string) will return a string representation of the array but I cannot find a setting to return a string in the exact format you want.

You could try to vectorize the conversion as much as possible, and finally do a `join` on the sequence:

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: str(int(x)))
"".join(vfunc(arr))
```

Output:

```
'000000100'
```

**EDIT**

This will do the same thing and is slightly faster and more readable.

```
"".join(arr.astype(np.dtype('<U1')))
```

In the case of a 2D array you can do this:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: "".join(x), 1, arr.astype(np.dtype('<U1')))
```

Comment: i have tried this values = ','.join(predict.astype(np.dtype('<U1'))) but am getting TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.ndarray found

Comment: What ```dtype``` and ```shape``` is predict?

Comment: dtype is float32

Comment: This should work if predict is 1d. Try to flatten the array otherwise.

Comment: the array is 2D. I provided just one instance of the predict results

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: If you want it all outputs concatenated as one string you need to do another ```join```, like this: ```"\n".join(...)```.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular array, something like

```
''.join([str(int(x)) for x in predict])
```

will do the trick.

To me, it's the list comprehension that makes it "pythonic", but that would be up for debate I guess...

For 2D-arrays, you can do

```
[''.join([str(int(x)) for x in y]) for y in predict]
```

to get a list of the strings that you asked for.

Comment: got this error implementing the above TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Same problem here as with Kevin's original solution. You did not mention 2D in your original question. I've added the fix in my answer.